# Migrating to core, but stuck with old "Module" (HttpApplication)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've done some parts for the Middleware in startup etc..

So this is my class

```c#
    public class AcceptQueryMiddleware
    {
        private const string Realm = "Basic realm=My Sales System";
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        private static readonly IDictionary<Regex, string> FormatAcceptMap = new Dictionary<Regex, string>();

        public AcceptQueryMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public void AcceptQueryHttpModule()
        {
            RegisterFormatAcceptQuery("csv", "text/csv");
            RegisterFormatAcceptQuery("excel", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
            RegisterFormatAcceptQuery("nav", "application/navision");
        }

        private static void RegisterFormatAcceptQuery(string format, string acceptHeader)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"([?]|[&])format=" + format);
            FormatAcceptMap.Add(regex, acceptHeader);
        }

        private static void OnApplicationBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var app = sender as HttpApplication;
            if (app == null) { return; }

            var url = app.Request.RawUrl;
            foreach (var format in FormatAcceptMap)
            {
                if (format.Key.Match(url).Success)
                {
                    app.Request.Headers["Accept"] = format.Value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

How do I convert it to Core? Way around it?
Specifically the `HttpApplication` that is not supported in .NET Core..

Or do you have any links or tips I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to migrate your HTTP module to a middleware. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules) to learn how.

In your case, you're using the `HttpApplication` to access request-related data. You're getting the raw URL and adding some headers. That's something you can [easily](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/writing-custom-middleware-in-asp-net-core-1-0/#otherexamplemiddleware) do in a middleware. Here's an example:

```csharp
    public class AcceptQueryMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public AcceptQueryMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            // Do your "before" stuff here (use the HttpContext)

            await _next.Invoke(context);

            // Do your "after" stuff here
        }
    }
```

and call `app.UseMiddleware<AcceptQueryMiddleware>();` in your `Startup` class (in the `Configure` method).

Comment: I already did this before but somehow I made my class a bit different from this middleware.. I'll go back to how it was before! thanks